# Transfer personal files and settings from old Win7 to new Win10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

My current computer runs Windows 7 and has been in use for five or six years now. Over that time I've accumulated a whole lot of personal settings, save games and files I really rather not lose.

I recently set myself up with a new comp with Windows 10 on it. What's considered best practice migrating settings and personal config files from one to the other? (I've already copied most of the large data and my multimedia library, so that's sorted).

Comment: Microsoft offers a free copy of a third-party software tool to do exactly this.

Comment: [Here](http://pcmoverfree.azurewebsites.net/), if you want to find the Microsoft Site, you can do on your own.

Comment: Microsoft has partnered with Laplink to bring PCmover Express. But it seems that this tool is unavailable now. EaseUS todo backup is a free download for home users. You can use the free version of this software.. I have used this and it works well..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using this tutorial on [how to transfer programs and files to a new computer](http://www.zinstall.com/how-to/how-to-transfer-programs-and-files-to-new-computer).

Used it a couple of times, worked just fine (not free, but I think worth the cash).

Or - if you don't need programs/settings, and just want the files - you can also just use a USB drive and copy the contents of C:\users\your-user-name. This will cover 80% of files you need, for free.

Comment: Please quote and cite all relevant information. Of course your "guide" suggested the exact same program that moonpoint suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provided [Windows Easy Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Easy_Transfer) for Windows Vista through Windows 8.1 systems.

> Windows Easy Transfer is a specialized file transfer program developed
>   by Microsoft which allows users of the Windows operating system to
>   transfer personal files and settings from a computer running an
>   earlier version of Windows to a computer running a newer version.
>
> Windows Easy Transfer was introduced in Windows Vista and is included
>   in the Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1 operating systems.

But that has been supplanted by Laplink's PCmover Express - see the [Wikipedia Windows Easy Transfer article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Easy_Transfer):

> The Windows Easy Transfer program was discontinued in Windows 10.
>   Microsoft has chosen to provide a free version of [Laplink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplink)'s [PCmover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCmover) Express as an
>   alternative to WET. A paid alternative is [Zinstall Easy Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinstall_Easy_Transfer) (Zinstall
>   also allows to transfer programs, in addition to files).